# Problems with website migration - duplicator - cloudflare - gandi

Tags: migration, cloudflare

First of all, I am not a developer, so please bear with me!

I have a live version and a staging version (dev). My website is e-commerce, built with wordpress and woocommerce. My theme is storefront. My hosting provider is gandi.net. For backup and migration, I use duplicator pro.

So, yesterday I was getting a 500 (internal server error) when trying to upload a post to the blog. Trying to locate the problem, I broke my dev and since then I am trying to build it again.

Problem 1) While running the installer of duplicator, I was getting a non-secure connection warning, which was not letting me pass throught it. This issue was the same in all browsers (firefox is throwing a warning and doesn’t allow me to proceed, Opera and Edge keep refreshing, and the green lock left to the url keeps altering from secure to non-secure) and other pc’s as well. I can’t locate the source of this problem, but I managed to bypass it by adding a firefox plugin (smart https). The warning is still there, but it lets me proceed.

Problem 2) After the, duplicator begins extraction, but after a while I get a 524 timeout error. I had faced the same issue a couple of times recently, but after repeating the procedure a few times, it was ok. Now, the 524 error is the result of every extraction attempt with duplicator.

So, I sent a ticket to hosting provider (Gandi) and they replied “your instance is undersized for the code and traffic associated with the websites.” (Current plan is Small, with 2 php workers). The max_execution_time of PHP scripts is 180 seconds.

I upgrated my hosting plan to medium, doubling php workers. However, I still get this 524 error. So, I asked Gandi again and they replied “The error is being reported by Cloudflare. They might have a lower timeout value than the max_execution_time of PHP. I suggest temporarily disabling Cloudflare filtering for this website (click on the Orange cloud next to the DNS record at Cloudflare), and then try running the installer again.”

So, I changed the CNAME dev from orange to grey and tried again.

In my first attempt, I got the following error: An error occurred during a connection to dev.meliory.gr. SSL peer has no certificate for the requested DNS name. Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

I tried again, the installer run normally and finally got again this 524 error.

Please assist, I am totally lost!

I appologize for the long post and the exhausting details, but I am not even sure which problem is relevant and which is irrelevant!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I was able to turn off the RailGun feature and I quit getting server time outs.  Then turned it back on.  No problems.  Check out the Railgun footnote in this support article: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171926-Error-524-A-timeout-occurred